# Simple List<string> vs IEnumarble<string> Performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, collections

I've tested `List<string>` vs `IEnumerable<string>`
iterations with `for` and `foreach` loops , is it possible that the List is much faster ?

these are 2 of few links I could find that are publicly stating that performance is better iterating `IEnumerable` over `List`.

[Link1](http://he.scribd.com/doc/93775737/What-is-The-Difference-Between-IEnumerable-and-List)
[Link2](http://venkyshandbook.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/ienumerable-vs-list.html)

my tests was loading  10K lines from a text file that holds a list of  URLs.

I've first loaded it in to a List , then  copied List to an IEnumerable

```
List<string> StrByLst = ...method to load records from the file .
IEnumerable StrsByIE =  StrByLst;
```

so each has 10k items Type `<string>`

looping on each  collection for 100 times , meaning 100K iterations, resulted with

`List<string>` is faster by amazing  **50 x**  than the `IEnumerable<string>`

is that predictable ?

- update

this is the code that is doing the tests

```C#
string WorkDirtPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
    string fileName = "tst.txt";
    string fileToLoad = Path.Combine(WorkDirtPath, fileName);
    List<string> ListfromStream = new List<string>();
    ListfromStream =  PopulateListStrwithAnyFile(fileToLoad) ;
    IEnumerable<string> IEnumFromStream = ListfromStream ;

    string trslt = "";
    Stopwatch SwFr = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch SwFe = new Stopwatch();

    string resultFrLst = "",resultFrIEnumrable, resultFe = "", Container = "";

    SwFr.Start();

    for (int itr = 0; itr < 100; itr++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListfromStream.Count(); i++)
        {
            Container = ListfromStream.ElementAt(i);
        }
    //the stop() was here , i was doing changes , so my mistake.
    }

   SwFr.Stop();
   resultFrLst = SwFr.Elapsed.ToString();
   //forgot to do this reset though still it is faster (x56??)
   SwFr.Reset();
   SwFr.Start();
        for(int itr = 0; itr<100; itr++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < IEnumFromStream.Count(); i++)
            {
                Container = IEnumFromStream.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }
    SwFr.Stop();
    resultFrIEnumrable = SwFr.Elapsed.ToString();
```

**Update ... final**

taking out the counter to outside of the for loops ,

`int counter = ..count`for both IEnumerable & List

then passed counter(int) as a count of total items as suggested by @ScottChamberlain .
re checked that every thing is in place, now the results are 5 % faster IEnumerable.
so that concludes , use by scenario - use case... no performance difference at all ...

Comment: please post actual code....

Comment: @MitchWheat will do .. right now

Comment: So what values do you get with each call to `SwFr.Elapsed` and is this a debug build?

Comment: I don't think I would put much trust a source of information that goes on to explain the `Differences between EXE and DLL`. But it's worth pointing out that you're not actually enumerating over the list, you're getting the element at `i` every time rather than asking for the `.Next()`

Comment: @nick_w i thought 10k items are not enough than i put an outer loop closed it after end of inner but left the stoper inside - outside inner (10k items only one go).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems with your test, one is the `IEnumFromStream.Count()` inside the `for` loop, every time it want to get that value it must enumerate over the entire list to get the count and the value is not cached between loops. Move that call outside of the `for` loop and save the result in a `int` and use that value for the `for` loop, you will see a shorter time for your IEnumerable.

Also the `IEnumFromStream.ElementAt(i)` behaves similarly to `Count()` it must iterate over the whole list up to `i` (eg: first time it goes `0`, second time `0,1`, third `0,1,2`, and so on...) every time where `List` can jump directly to the index it needs. You should be working with the [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) returned from [`GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx) instead.

`IEnumerable`'s and `for` loop's don't mix well. Use the correct tool for the job, either call [`GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx) and work with that or use it in a `foreach` loop.

---

Now, I know a lot of you may be saying "But it is a interface it will be just mapping the calls and it should make no difference", but there is a key thing, `IEnumerable<T>` ***Does not have a `Count()` or `ElementAt()` method!***. Those methods are extension methods added by LINQ, and the LINQ classes do not know the underlying collection is a List, so it does what it knows the underlying object can do, and that is iterating over the list every time the method is called.

---

### `IEnumerable` using `IEnumerator`

```
using(var enu = IEnumFromStream.GetEnumerator())
{
    //You have to call "MoveNext()" once before getting "Current" the first time,
    //   this is done so you can have a nice clean while loop like this.
    while(enu.MoveNext())
    {
        Container = enu.Current;
    }
}
```

The above code is basically the same thing as

```
foreach(var enu in IEnumFromStream)
{
    Container = enu;
}
```

The important thing to remember is `IEnumerable`'s do not have a length, in fact they can be infinitely long. There is [a whole field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) of computer science on detecting a infinitely long `IEnumerable`

Comment: I think that your last edit is the key point: both `Count` and `ElementAt` are implemented as extension methods of `IEnumerable`, so the results shouldn't be materially different between tests. After all, the OP is using these two methods in both runs. I would have expected differences if the first test used the `Count` property and accessed the item with `ListfromStream[i]`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain could you please write some example code for  iteration on `IEnumerable` the way you describe and what are the keys /is the key difference ?

Comment: @LoneXcoder I added a example showing the raw usage of a `IEnumerable`, but I would just use a `foreach`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain nice to know , i will get *acquainted* with it's fetures thanks for the extra information

Answer (score 4):

You are doing something wrong.

The times that you get should be very close to each other, because you are running essentially the same code.

IEnumerable is just an interface, which List implements, so when you call some method on the IEnumerable reference it ends up calling the corresponding method of List.

There is no code implemented in the IEnumerable - this is what interfaces are - they only specify what functionality a class should have, but say nothing about how it's implemented.

Comment: +1 the code supplied performs the exact same. The OP has something else that is causing the difference in performance.

Comment: yes i did some changes putting outer loop as well , did not pay attention on that closer "}" being after first time inner loop was done, my mistake. i was already late . next time dont work under pressure , is mi advice .

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted I think the problem is with your use of the `Stopwatch` class.

You declare two of these, `SwFr` and `SwFe`, but only use the former. Because of this, the last call to `SwFr.Elapsed` will get the total amount of time across *both* sets of `for` loops.

If you are wanting to reuse that object in this way, place a call to `SwFr.Reset()` right after `resultFrLst = SwFr.Elapsed.ToString();`.

Alternatively, you could use `SwFe` when running the second test.

Comment: `swFe` targetted the later test ForEach... i had huge flaws i did not check properly before comming to final concloution, i had to go somewhere so only when i came back checking my code , i spotted the wrong place i left the Stop() after former test that was without the outer x100 for.